# When using an image as the background of a minipage how to remove the black frame around it?

Tags: minipage, framed

I have a question about a piece of code the moderator Martin Scharrer posted some time ago (so if you're there Martin, this one is for you). The question he was answering to was about using an image as the background of a `minipage`.

He posted this solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mysavebox
\newenvironment{imgminipage}[2][]{%
   \def\imgcmd{\includegraphics[width=\wd\mysavebox,height=\dimexpr\ht\mysavebox+\d    p\mysavebox\relax,#1]{#2}}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\mysavebox}%
   \begin{minipage}%
}{%
   \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}%
   \sbox\mysavebox{\fbox{\usebox\mysavebox}}%
   \mbox{\rlap{\raisebox{-\dp\mysavebox}{\imgcmd}}\usebox\mysavebox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{imgminipage}{imagefilename}{5cm}
Some text\\
Hello world!
\end{imgminipage}

\end{document}
```

When I use this code, however, the `minipage` has a black frame around the image. How can I modify it to get rid of the frame?

Comment: Replace `\fbox` with `\mbox`. `\fbox` is for frame box.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
\sbox\mysavebox{\fbox{\usebox\mysavebox}}
```

restores `\mysavebox` with an `\fbox` around it. Remove this line and your output should appear *without* the `f`ramed `box`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. But now I have a problem of a different sort. When I use fbox there is a small distance between the text and the borders of the image (I'm using an image that has no white bits). When I use mbox, however, the image ends just as the body of the text ends. How can I restore that small distance?

Comment: @Gabu: Then you may want to keep the `\fbox`, but add `\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}` to your preamble. This will remove the rule around the image, but keep the `\fboxsep` white space around it.

Comment: Like a charm, mate. Thank you very much. One last thing... do you know how can I make this distance bigger?

Comment: The default `\fboxsep` is `3pt`. You could add `\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}` to your preamble to change this globally, or at the start of your `imgminipage` environment (similar for `\fboxrule`) to limit it to that specific environment. You can also do something like `\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5\fboxsep}` to increase the current `\fboxsep` by 50%.